# How to avoid UnexpectedAlertOpen - Intern Leadfoot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, intern, leadfoot

I have a written a intern functional test which copies data from one cell and pastes it to another cell. The problem is every time run the test and copy the data I get a dialogue box with the message

`Pasting from clipboard is
currently turned off by your browser.Local Data will be
used`
Now because of this popup my functional test freezes and everything else starts to fails. Luckily to avoid this there is a way. `.acceptAlert()`

```
.copyfunction()
.sleep(500) //wait for popup
.acceptAlert() //first attempt to copy after login causes alert about using local memory                    
.pastefunction()
```

Although this works locally there are times the test still fails when in jenkins. Its not stable. How do I make it stable.

Comment: Is it changing load time for the popup to appear that is causing the failures in Jenkins?  If so, you'll probably want to add a fluent wait instead of the sleep to add some stability.

Comment: I guess it may be due to the pop up being loaded with delay. Can you provide an example ?

Comment: I misspoke with the first comment, and I think the ExplicitWait would be better for your situation.  Here is a link to all of the wait types with examples: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/

Comment: I am using the intern framework.

Comment: Is there an id associated with the popup?

Comment: the popup is a browser related which occured when I try to copy/paste on the browser. If there was a id i would pollUntil but its not a part of the DOM. The UI thread freezes and hence all my test fails